# RAW to NTFS (Data already recovered so not important)

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, ntfs, format

Recently something went wrong with my external WD passport. It is not accesible anymore in Win 7 and the type is now currently RAW. I recovered all the data so formatting it is no issue.

I tried formatting it with windows but it seems to be unable to do so. Does anyone have any suggestions how I am able to get this RAW drive back to NTFS or FAT or whatever.. as long as it works.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like the usb chip in the enclosure is having problems, the drive may be good but the enclosure is dying.

Comment: Well all the issues started after I wanted to format 1/2 partitions on the drive. It formatted both of them and well has stopped the disk being accessible through windows. I got my files back with TestDisk but got stuck from there.

Comment: One way to tell if the enclosure is wonky, is to remove the drive from the enclosure and connect it directly to a motherboard or use another usb to hard drive adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the partition in Disk Administrator (diskmgmt.msc), re-create it, then format it.

Comment: And of which manufacturer is this Partition Manager? I've found two different ones on google. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Just plug it into Windows, and use its partition manager.Control Panel>System and Security>Administrative Tools>Computer Management. Then in that, Storage>Disk Management. Right click the partition and delete it.

Comment: As Moab said, if this does not work, then the enclosure may be dying.