# Converting a raw file system to NTFS

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RAW to NTFS (Data already recovered so not important)](https://superuser.com/questions/305250/raw-to-ntfs-data-already-recovered-so-not-important)

My hard disk is being corrupted and now it became a raw file system. I tried to format, but Windows can't complete the task.

Are there any ways to convert the filesystem back to NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The easiest way will be to repartition the drive.  If Windows Setup won't let you, `diskpart.exe`'s `clean` command from a Recovery Console should do the trick to let you repartition the drive.

However, you really need to figure out *why* this is happening, or it's going to happen again.  Hard Drives don't magically corrupt themselves.  If you didn't to anything to cause it, you very likely have failing (or failed!) hardware.

Comment: not really sure how to use the diskpart.exe..

i'm trying to figure out also, as i have two harddisk and one thumbdrive already become raw file system.

Comment: `list disk` will show you a list of drives.  You should be able to identify the HD you want to install on by its capacity.  If not, disconnect your data drives until you're done with the installation.  `select disk n` will select the drive (where *n* is the matching disk number from the output of `list disk`).  `clean` will erase the 1st MB, which contains the boot sector & partition table.  From there you can exit and go into the regular Windows setup to repartition the drive as a blank, new drive.